# How to add GTM code to header.php but other code already after <body>?

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit header.php to add Google Tag Manager. The WordPress theme is Bridge and there seems to be lots of people out there with the same problem. Adding it directly isn't working so I am trying Google Tag Manager plugin for WordPress. The default method doesn't work so I am trying the custom method. I need to add the following line just after the opening  tag:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>
```

Trouble is there is code there already:

```
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<?php
```

How do I merge the two without breaking anything? Thank you!

Comment: You may either create child theme of your theme and copy header.php to child theme  and paste your code at that place you want to add it How to create 

Child Theme - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Or You may use `wp_head` hook to add it but child theme must be suggested because when your theme will get update it won't lose your custom code - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/

Comment: Thank you. So would this work.. ,,,</head> <body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="schema.org/WebPage"> <?php<?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>

Comment: You should be write something like this `<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>`

Comment: Thank you Krunal but that didn't work. Is there anything in the lines immediately above or below that could be breaking it?  </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>

<?php
$params = qode_header_parameters();
extract($params);

Comment: It looks fine to me but make sure that GTM plugin should be active

Comment: The plugin is definitely active.

Comment: Then code looks fine check other things

Comment: Sorted. It just needed a cache refresh!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add the PHP code as an attribute of the body tag or a child element of the body tag?
If you want to add it as body tag attribute, then use the body_class filter in functions.php file ( preferably in a child theme ) and add the code in the function callback.
Find more about using the body_class filter hook.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/

If you want to add the code as a child element of the body tag, then after the opening body tag (`<body .... >`) just add the code.

Comment: Thank you. So would this work.. ,,,</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<?php<?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>,,,

Comment: Yes that should work. Do remove the additional opening php tag(<?php) though.